# C# Com Interop: Set Background Colour Of A Row

Tags: c#, excel, com, interop

I have an Excel worksheet that was created with this code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Workbook wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];
```

I would like to iterate over the rows and for each row with a certain value in the second column I would like to change the background colour of this row to red.

Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Worksheets have a `UsedRange` which has a `Rows` collection - each `Row` has a `Cells` collection - a `Cell` has a `Value` and an `Interior.Color` property which takes an RGB (Long) value.

Answer (score 2):

What you are wanting to do is conditional formatting using the interop. Microsoft has a straight forward example here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb404903.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Code below creates an Excel file, fills it with random values and than if value in A column more than 5, transform background color to green.

```
        Random rnd = new Random();

        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(Excel.XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
        Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];

        // Set random data in A column
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            ws.Range["A" + i, Type.Missing].Value = rnd.Next(10);
            ws.Range["B" + i, Type.Missing].Value = rnd.Next(10);
        }

        // Set background if value in cell A more than 5
        int rowNum = 0;
        foreach (Excel.Range range in ws.Range["A1", "A10"])
        {
            rowNum++;

            if (range.Value > 5)
            {
                foreach (Excel.Range rowRange in ws.Range["A" + rowNum, "B" + rowNum])
                {
                    var colorScale = (Excel.ColorScale)rowRange.FormatConditions.AddColorScale(2);
                    colorScale.ColorScaleCriteria[2].FormatColor.Color = 0x0000FF00;
                }
            }
        }

        // Save and close file
        wb.SaveAs("C:\\1234567890.xlsx");
        wb.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        xlApp.Quit();
```